# How to change the appearance of a button once it has been clicked in libre impress

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I have what should be a fairly straightforward question regarding libre impress. I want to make several buttons to jump around the document and I would also like these buttons to indicate that they have been clicked before.

To achieve this I used simple shapes (stars in my case) and added an interaction feature to jump to the desired location. So far so simple. In order to indicate that a button has been clicked before, I thought the easiest way would be to change transparency, colour or size of the shapes. Really any of those would be fine for me. I thought this could be done with a macro. My problems are the following:

1. I don't know how to write the macro. I have a rudimentary understanding of scripting (mostly Python) but not with this particular language.
2. I don't seem to be able to attach two interactions to one object (i.e. one for the jumping and one one for the macro to change the appearance).

I hope that there is a simple solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I have what should be a fairly straightforward question` — a strong clue that in all likelihood this will be a difficult question! This is 2nd [order of ignorance](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2000/10/7556-the-five-orders-of-ignorance/fulltext).

Answer (score 0):

The tag is for Basic, so I'll go with that. However, LibreOffice macros can also be written in Python. To get started with Python macros, use [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) and check out [this tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html).

Anyway, here is some Basic code for Impress to point you in the right direction.

```
oDoc = ThisComponent
oDrawPage = oDoc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)
oShape = oDrawPage.getByIndex(0)
mri(oShape)
MsgBox(oShape.getControl().Label)
```

Whether you decide on Basic or Python, get the MRI extension in order to discover UNO properties of an object. This way you can find out how to change the button.

When you have some code, post another question or edit this one that shows the code you have so far, and describe problems you encountered.